# Issue while change property of item in ListView while filtering

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, filter, collectionview

I have a list of items that can be filtered. The Item class has a property IsChecked. Sometimes, if I change this property (in Runtime via a Checkbox) while the list is filtered, it does not change it in my source collection. Am I doing it wrong ?

```
public class ViewModel 
{
     private ObservableCollection<Item> _items;
     public ListCollectionView ItemsView { get; private set; }
     private bool _checkAll;

     public bool CheckAll
     {
          get
          {
               return _checkAll;
          }
          set
          {
               if (_checkAll == value)
                    return;

               _checkAll = value;

               if (_checkAll)
               {
                    foreach (Item i in ItemsView )
                         i.IsChecked = true;
               }
               else
               {
                    foreach (Item i in ItemsView )
                         i.IsChecked = false;
               }

               OnPropertyChanged("CheckAll");
          }
     }

     public ViewModel()
     {
          _items= new ObservableCollection<Item>(this.createList());
          ItemsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_items) as ListCollectionView;
          ItemsView.Filter = filter;
     }

     private void filter(object obj)
     {
          ...
     }

}

public class Item
{
     private bool _isChecked;

     public Item()
     {
     }

     public bool IsChecked
     {
          get {return _isChecked; }
          set
          {
               if (_isChecked == value)
                    return;
               _isChecked = value;
               OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
          }
     }

     ...
}
```

Comment: How and where are you using CheckAll property?

Comment: could you also post your Item class and its IsChecked Property?

Comment: The CheckedAll property is bind to a CheckBox in the Header of the first column of the ListView. The IsChecked property is bind to the column itself. When i select an item in a list (via the checkbox) and then filter the list, select another item and then clear filters, the selected items is not correct. Sorry for my english

Comment: i think i would remove the if statement that returns without the OnPropertyChanged at the setter of IsChecked and try again

Comment: Can we see how you have your XAML set up?

Comment: How do you know it is not changing in the source collection?

Answer (score 0):

I think that nothing is wrong with your code, let me explain:

When you perform this operation:

```
foreach (Item i in ItemsView )
     i.IsChecked = true;
```

you are setting the IsChecked property to true only for the items that the ListView is currently showing (i.e. only the ones that pass the filter).

If you want to set ALL elements in your ObservableCollection _items to true or false, you can achieve this in two different ways:

```
foreach (Item i in _items) //enumerate the private ObservableCollection
     i.IsChecked = true;
```

or

```
foreach (Item i in ItemsView.SourceCollection) //enumerate the underlying ObservableCollection
     i.IsChecked = true;
```

If the Item class implements INotifyPropertyChanged the UI should reflect the changes without problem.

---

Edit 1 (based on discussion below):

Another way to check/unchek your items would be:

```
public bool CheckAll
 {
      get { return _checkAll; }
      set
      {
           if (_checkAll == value)
                return;

           _checkAll = value;

           _items.Where(ItemsView.Filter.Invoke).Select(i=>i.IsChecked=_checkAll);

           OnPropertyChanged("CheckAll");
      }
 }
```

Enumerating the ListView should work ok, but since it isn't this is a way around it, to work directly with your collection, but taking into account the filtered elements.

---

Hope this helps, regards!

Comment: I know that, it is not the problem. Let assume i have a list which contains 5 items. 4 of these items have a label which begins by "80". I have a textbox to filter this list. When i enter "80" on it, the list show 4 items. I then check these 4 items and clear the texbox so the list now displays 5 items. I uncheck the 4 items which were previously checked. When i filter again the list by entering "80" in the textbox. The 4 items are still checked while i unchecked them. 

Sorry for my english, i hope you understand me

Comment: Sometimes, the property IsChecked Set is called when the filter of the list has changed. I don't know why..

Comment: Does the Item class implement INotifyPropertyChanged for the IsChecked property? The get and set accesors should be public, also.

Comment: Yes the Item class implement INotifyPropertyChanged and the get and set accessors are public

Comment: Are you doing this: 

foreach (Item i in _items)
     i.IsChecked = true;

or this:

foreach (Item i in ItemsView )
                         i.IsChecked = true;

??

Comment: The problem also occurs when i manually check an item during Runtime. I check the first item then filter the list, the first item is still checked -> OK. Then i clear the filter and uncheck the first item then i filter the list again and the item is still check while i uncheck it. 

Sometimes the property IsChecked(set) of my item is called when i filter the list

Comment: I understand what is happening. Please be specific about my previous question:

 
Are you doing this: foreach (Item i in _items) i.IsChecked = true; or this: foreach (Item i in ItemsView ) i.IsChecked = true; ??

Comment: i use foreach (Item i in ItemsView ) i.IsChecked = true;

Comment: Try foreach (Item i in _items) i.IsChecked = true; and let me know

Comment: i tryed. it changed nothing except it select all the items in the list, even those who are not shown in the filtered list

Comment: ok, it should do so, check everything even if it is not in the list. When you uncheck and filter again, they still appear checked? Make sure you use the same  (Item i in _items) i.IsChecked = true/false for checking and unchecking

Comment: Yes they still appear checked :(. When i filter the list again, the property IsChecked of all the item i previously uncheck is called and it change the value again. Why the property is call again ?

Comment: If i uncheck/check/uncheck the item after clear the filter, it works but not if i uncheck one time..